# Ubuntu 13.04 desktop background problem

Tags: unity, 13.04, desktop-environments, desktop-background

I have a problem with my desktop background after last update.

My Desktop wall paper looks like mosaic and when I open any window, the background keeps the trail of it.

I've tried running in fail safe graphics more, no fix. I've tried installing ubuntu-desktop and unity, no fix.

Please help.

[image: Mosaic background]

[image: Window trail]

Comment: Graphics Adapter Make and Model?

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is missing dependencies with unity and compiz. Type apt-get build-dep compiz, then apt-get build-dep unity. Should clear that problem up after a reboot. Now me I have the wallpaper/effects but no taskbars side or upper! So if anyone knows how to clear that up, would be grateful!!! Running multiple desktops Gnome 3.8, KDE, LXDE, XFCE etc.